# MS Graph API: Getting 404 when saving to _layouts folder

Tags: java, sdk, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the MS Graph Java SDK to save a file to user's OneDrive and under a given path:

```
@Test
public void createDriveItem() {
    String fileName = "moon.pdf";
    String fullPath = "a/_layouts/b" + fileName;
    byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName));
    graph.users(userId)
            .drive()
            .root()
            .itemWithPath(encodePath(fullPath))
            .content()
            .buildRequest()
            .put(content);
}

private String encodePath(String path) {
    String encoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(path, encoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return path;
    }
}
```

I'm using MS Graph Java SDK v2.5.0, Java 11.

However, this request fails with `404 : Not Found`. It also fails if I don't encode the path. It looks like the `/_layouts/` which is making troubles because, once I add something to it, the request works.

Also, I reproduced this error with a number of accounts.

My question is: Is this actually expected? If yes, why does creating the same folder structure work when done through the web UI?

Comment: I havent used the Sdk but i tried using the Graph API directly and it works for me (using POSTMAN/Graph explorer). Have you tried it as well? This will help you to isolate the issue. Also try to use the latest SDK and see if you can repro the issue as well

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not be able to add items into /_layouts/ on SharePoint Online.